# Restrict editing access of webpages in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-website

It would be great to extend the odoo website module with some additional features. Obviously a new module needs to be created. **Not every website user should be allowed to edit every page of the website.**

**Example:** Company X uses the website module in odoo. Admin A prepares the homepage of the website by using the website builder. Now user B opens the website builder. He should not be able to edit selected pages like the homepage, contact us page ... but get access to some features like adding and editing a new page about some topics.

Is that possible and what's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/security.html, to be able to modify a record (on the `website.page` model in this case) the user access rights (on `ir.model.access`) are checked.

So, I would suggest creating/editing a group, add some users and then go to the "Record Rules" tab and add a line such as the following:

- Name: Disable homepage editing
- Object: Page (`website.page`)
- Domain: `[('id','not in',[1])]`
- Apply for read: [x]
- Apply for write: [x]
- Apply for create: [ ]
- Apply for delete: [ ]

That rule should allow the group members to edit (`write`) a website page as long as its `id` is not 1 (that is, homepage).

Note: You can't use `ref` on the domain expression, only two objects are available in the context: `user` (the current user) and `time` (the Python module).